# How to create library file from an windows phone 8 application in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dll, visual-studio-2013

There is any way to create library file from an windows phone 8 application in visual studio 2013.I try to create class library project but UI designer was not there. I want to create an library with UI design i am new for Windows phone development.

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Portable Class Library

[image]